# Error when upload a yml with cluster policy bindings in openshift "already exist"

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

When I try to execute this:

```
oc create -f custom_clusterPolicyBinding.yml
Error from server: error when creating "custom_clusterPolicyBinding.yml": clusterpolicybindings ":default" already exists

oc version
oc v1.4.1
kubernetes v1.4.0+776c994
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO
```

This is the custom_clusterPolicyBinding.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ClusterPolicyBinding
metadata:
  name: custom
policyRef:
  name: custom
roleBindings:
- name: custom:label-nodos
  roleBinding:
    groupNames:
    - pachi
    metadata:
      name: custom:label-nodos
    roleRef:
      name: custom:label-nodos
    subjects:
    - kind: Group
      name: pachi
    userNames: null
```

The cluster role binding custom:label-nodos already exist

```
oc get clusterroleBinding | grep custom:label-nodos
custom:label-nodos                              /custom:label-nodos
```

And the content of cluster role binding yaml is:

```
apiVersion: v1
groupNames: null
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: custom:label-nodos
roleRef:
  name: custom:label-nodos
subjects: []
userNames: null
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not directly edit policy.  There is only one cluster policy and cluster policy binding.

Instead you would want to create a `clusterrole` with content similar to this (edit it to grant the permissions you want to give out):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: some-user
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - project.openshift.io
  - ""
  resources:
  - projects
  verbs:
  - list
```

And a `clusterrolebinding` with content like this (edit it to bind to the correct subjects):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: some-users
roleRef:
  name: some-user
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: foo
```

You can also use the `oadm policy add-*role-to-*` commands to help with binding roles:

```
add-cluster-role-to-group
add-cluster-role-to-user
add-role-to-group
add-role-to-user
```